# Is it possible to have Ran A = Ker $A^{T}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Is it possible to have $\text{rank }A$ = $\ker A^{T}$ when $A$ is a real matrix? I think the answer is no, but I'm not sure about how to prove it. What about when $A$ is a complex matrix? Here, I think the answer is yes, but I cannot come up with an example.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Can you find a matrix $A$ such that $A^TA=0$?  That would show that Ran $A \subseteq$ Ker $A^T$.

Comment: The zero matrix ?

Comment: That solves the simpler problem I gave you in the comment, but you won't get equality.  Can you find a non-zero matrix that's an example?

Comment: i don't think i can come up with anything

Comment: how'd you get $A^{T}A = 0$?

Comment: Given any vector $x$, you know that $Ax$ is in the kernel of $A^T$, and so $A^T(Ax) = 0$; that is, we know $AA^T = 0$ since $A^TAx=0$ for any vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The range of $A^t$ is $(\operatorname{ker}A)^{\perp}$, in general.

Thus there are no (nontrivial) examples. That is,  this implies we're in the zero vector space.

Comment: What about for complex matrices?

Comment: I don't think so.   We still get $\operatorname{ker}A=(\operatorname{ker}A)^{\perp}$, a contradiction.

Comment: what about $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -i \\ i & 1 \end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: Looks like you're right.   The columns consist of nonzero vectors whose norm would be zero.  I guess it isn't a normed vector space, or something.   Very good.

Comment: Note, the standard inner product on a complex vector space is defined with a 'wrinkle' to rule this out.  Namely,   a complex conjugate is thrown in:  $v\cdot w=v_1\bar {w_1}+v_2\bar{w_2}$.  But no one said the vector had to be normed, I guess.  Hmm.  Actually the use of 'perp' suggests an inner product.   Apparently your example would work with the standard inner product.   Hmm.  Food for thought.

Answer (score 0):

$Ran(A)=Ker A^T$ implies that $AA^T=0$, this implies that $\langle AA^T(x),x\rangle=\langle A^T(x),A^T(x)\rangle=0$ implies $A^T=A=0$.

Comment: Then we need to make the further observation that the zero matrix isn't a solution (because its range is $\{0\}$ but its kernel is the whole space), so there is no solution.

Comment: how does that last equality imply $A^{T} = A$?